# Netezza table size increased after using CTAS command

Tags: netezza, aginity

I have a large table in Netezza and table size is approx 600 GB.
When I tried to create a new table from my existing table the table size has increased. New table size is 617 GB.

SQL which I used to create new table:
create table new_table_name as select * from old_table_name distribution on (column_name);
generate statistics on new_table_name;
However row count for new table and old table are same.

What could be the reason for increasing table size?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the distribution of `old_table_name` also on `column_name`?

Comment: No. In old table we don't have any distribution key.

Comment: And when you say "table size", do you mean used space or allocated space?

Comment: Old Table - 
Used MB 612606 and Total MB 614126;

New Table - 
Used MB 635627 and Total MB 636985.

Answer (score 0):

There are two relevant measurements for 'size' of a table: allocated and used size (both in bytes)
_v_table_storage_stat will help you look at both sizes for a given table

For small tables, the allocated size can be many times larger than the used size, and assuming an even distribution of rows, a minimum of 3MB will be allocated on each data slice. I do most of my work on a double rack MAKO system with 480 data slices. Therefore any table with less than 14,4GB are more or less irrelevant for optimization of 'size'

Nevertheless I'll try to explain what you see:
You must realize that 
1) all data in Netezza are compressed. 
2) Compression is being done for a 'block' of data on each individual dataslice.
3) Compression ratio (the size of data after compression divided by the size before) gets better (smaller) if data in each block share many similarities compared to the most 'mixed' situation imaginable. 
4) 'distribute on' and 'organize on' can both affect this. The same can an 'order by' or even a 'group by' in the select statement used when adding data to your table

In my system, I have a very wide table with several 'copies' per day of the bank accounts of our customers. Each copy are 99% identical to the previous one and only things like 'balance' changes.

By distributing on accountID and organizing on AccountID,Timestamp - I saw a 10-15% smaller size. Some data slices had a better effect, because they contained a lot of 'system' account ID's which have a different pattern in the data.

In short: 
A) it's perfectly natural 
B) don't worry too much about it since:
C) a 'large' table on a Netezza system is not the same as on a 4-core database with too little memory and sloooow disks  :)